# Retrieving DataStream list in Elasticsearch using python API

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, eland

In Kibana dev tools, When I am using the API call `GET /_data_stream/`
I am getting the list of DataStream.
In similar way I want to retrieve it using the Elasticsearch Python API, I am not able to find the way. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below python code as describe [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.get_data_stream):

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=["localhost:9200"])
resp= es.indices.get_data_stream(name="*")
```